# Select last record only if a certain condition is met

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains an ID, WorkerID, a flag (1 or 0) to show when they are on or off shift and a date when that flag value was logged. I would like to take from this table, for each unique workerID, the latest date a flag was logged (1 or 0) only if the flag of This latest date is equal to 1. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please provide sample data if you want actual query. Other than that: use row_number to achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you seem to want the rows of users where the log flag is 1.

This suggests `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by workerId order by date desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and flag = 1;
```

Note:  your question would be much better with sample data and desired results.

Comment: i understand the op wants the date per workerid